# how to pass parameter from HTML with Thymeleaf to Spring Controller?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a controller in Spring Boot that needs to recieve a parameter and an object by POST. The parameter is NOT an object or part of if.

Here is the Thymeleaf form without the parameter. It works fine in a stand-alone page, but the same code does not work when I use it in a page that shows an article:

```
<form th:action="@{/addcomment}" th:object="${comment}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{commenttext}" />
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

because when I add the

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:with="id=1" value="${id}"/>
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" value="1"/>
```

my Controller prints 0 in the console, when the value should be 1... (and even if I change it to value="true".... this comes from the Chrome console:

```
<input type="hidden" class="sr-only" value="0" id="id" name="id" />
```

no matter what I use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcomment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView addStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid Comment comment, @RequestParam("id") Long id, BindingResult result) {

    Comment commentform = new Comment();

    Announcement announcement = announcementService.readAnnouncement(id);

    String sanatizedcommenttext = htmlPolicy.sanitize(comment.getCommenttext());
    commentform.setCommenttext(sanatizedcommenttext);
    commentform.setDate(new Date());
    commentform.setAnnoucements(announcement);

    modelAndView.setViewName("addcomment");

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        commentService.createComment(commentform);

        modelAndView.getModel().put("comment2th", new Comment());
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/addcomment");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

By the way, the parameter is in the url (but I would like to know how to send it to the controller independently of where it is located).
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to add this changes

```
<input type="hidden" name="paramName" value="1"/>
```

In your Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcomment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView addStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid Comment comment, @RequestParam("paramName") Long id, BindingResult result) {
```

The problem was, that you were using the thymeleaf tags for input fields, then Spring thinks the attribute **id** its inside the object Comment, but it's not your case, so you have to use normal input tag.

Comment: FINALLY! I searched everywhere to understand this behaviour... thanks for clarifying